# AppWidget won't work

Tags: android, xml, widget, view, clock

I'm using a configuration activity to toggle visibilty of different views in the xml file using RemoteViews. At first i thought, since the configuration activity is called before the widget is set, i wouldnt need to update, so i used :

```
package com.example.test.clock.one;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.RemoteViews;

 public class chooseract extends Activity
 {
int mAppWidgetId;
RemoteViews rv;
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
Context context;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
}
public void buttonhandler(View view)
{
    rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        mAppWidgetId =  extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
        {
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock1, View.VISIBLE);
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock2, View.INVISIBLE);

                finish();
                            break;
        }
        case R.id.button2:
        {               
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock1, View.INVISIBLE);
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock2, View.VISIBLE);
            finish();
                            break;

        }
    }


}   
}
```

but that just sets a blank widget (default visibility is INVISIBLE)
then i tried updating the appwidget after toggling visibility using

```
package com.example.test.clock.one;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class chooseract extends Activity
{
int mAppWidgetId;
RemoteViews rv;
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
Context context;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
}
public void buttonhandler(View view)
{
    rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
        {
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock1, View.VISIBLE);
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock2, View.INVISIBLE);
            break;

        }
        case R.id.button2:
        {               
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock1, View.INVISIBLE);
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock2, View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        }
    }

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, rv);
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
    finish();
}   
}
```

but this just force closes when i touch the buttons with a NullPointerException
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private int mAppWidgetId;
private RemoteViews rv;
private AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    



    rv = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    AnalogClock cos1 = (AnalogClock)findViewById(R.id.analogClock1);
    AnalogClock cos2 = (AnalogClock)findViewById(R.id.analogClock2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
        {
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock1, View.VISIBLE);
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock2, View.INVISIBLE);
            break;

        }
        case R.id.button2:
        {               
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock1, View.INVISIBLE);
            rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.analogClock2, View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        }
    }

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, rv);
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
    finish();
}
```

}

I added few fixes and does not throw an error. :)

Comment: :O     i owe you BIG time       :O